# How to declare a function that accepts only two or zero arguments?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, if I declare a function like this

```
function foo(arg1?: any, arg2?: any)
```

Then the compiler won't complain if I call the function with

- Zero arguments
- One argument
- Two arguments

How should I declare the function if I want the compiler to complian about one argument but not two or zero?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use function overload:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads

```js
// Start with most specific overload signature
function foo(arg1: any, arg2: any): any; 

// And then, less specific overload signature
function foo(): any; 

// At the end, write your function implementation
function foo(arg1?: any, arg2?: any) {
  console.log(arguments);
}

foo(1, 'test'); // Ok
foo(); // Ok 
foo('a'); // Compile error
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. The other answers offer good solutions but this is what I need for my purposes.

Answer (score 2):

What I like to do in these type of situations:

```js
interface FooArgs {
    arg1: any;
    arg2: any;
}

function foo(arg?: FooArgs)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Called like this:
`foo({arg1: 'arg', arg2: 'arg2})` or `foo()`.

---

The typescript compiler will show an error if you try it like this:

```js
foo({arg1: 'arg'})
```

```
Argument of type '{ arg1: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FooArgs'. Property 'arg2' is missing in type '{ arg1: number; }' but required in type 'FooArgs'.
```

Try it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0EEoHMDOyA3gFDLnJx4CMAXJSAJ4DcZFVuATPXE6wL4kSMAK4gEYYOhDIYmABQcA-PQzY8%20AJQlSJQcIVEOdZNX6agA)

Comment: This is a nice solution but for my case, I don't think this works for me. Check my pull request [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/47251) to DefinitelyTyped. I don't have control over the source code of the library. The function I changed only accepts two or zero arguments. What should I do in this case?

Comment: I think @Manuel's answer covers my case.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, it's also possible to use spread args and only have one definition:

```
function foo(...args: [] | [ any, any ]) {
  console.log(args);
}

foo(1, 'test'); // Ok
foo(); // Ok 
foo('a'); // Compile error
```

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUA6LBDATgcwGcAuRAbQF1EAfcxbMATwBp6nEKBKRAbwChEiCAkJwANgFMMYuPjR4inANx8Avnz4p0ARlYByKBMJQ9yxAHpziAPIBrTajRnLN24gfo92U0otWAwnAAtgAOMJKIEri4cLh8QA)

Comment: This is certainly interesting and requires you to write less code but I think it's not as easily understandable as the function overload solution. Even the error message is not as clear as the one produced from that solution.

Comment: I agree that function overloading is the best option for your situation (but this may be useful in other cases).

Answer (score 1):

in this case I would transform params into array as:

```
function foo(params?: [any, any])  {

}

foo() //works
foo([0]) //error
foo([0, 0]) //works
```

or into object and do it like this:

```
interface BarArgs {
    arg1: any;
    arg2: any;
}

function bar(arg?: BarArgs) {

}

bar() //works
bar({arg1: 0}) //error
bar({arg2: 1}) //error
bar({arg1: 0, arg2: 1}) //works
```